# DOM function giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having problem with one of my navbars. I want to change the color of the button when a user clicks it. But the function doesn't seem to be working.
Here is the link to my website, where that nav located: [My Website](https://novostroyka.shahar.uz/complex/uzbegim)

Here`s the look of that nav menu:

[image: The nav]

```js
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)

var header = document.getElementById("navbar-complex");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("aactive");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" aactive", "");
    this.className += " aactive";
  });
}
```

```css
.aactive,
.a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar-complex" class="scrollmenu tab-content nav nav-tabs">
  <a href="#complex_view" class="aactive" data-toggle="tab">{$L_COMPLEX_VIEW}</a>
  <a href="#complex_single" data-toggle="tab">{$L_COMPLEX_SINGLE}</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*a* is not the class you are using in `header.getElementsByClassName("a")`, it is the tag name. You can use `querySelectorAll()` to target them from the *header*.

Also, I will suggest you the following:

1. You can use `querySelectorAll()` instead of `getElementsByClassName()` so that you can ignore the index.
2. You can use `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()` to add and remove *class* respectively.

**Demo:**

```js
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var header = document.getElementById("navbar-complex");
var btns = header.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.querySelector(".aactive"); //you can use querySelector to target the element with class aactive
    current.classList.remove("aactive"); //now you do not need to use the index 
    this.classList.add("aactive");
  });
}
```

```css
.aactive, .a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar-complex" class="scrollmenu tab-content nav nav-tabs">
  <a href="#complex_view" class="aactive" data-toggle="tab">COMPLEX VIEW</a>
  <a href="#complex_single"  data-toggle="tab">COMPLEX SINGLE</a>                           
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
var btns = header.getElementsByTagName("a");
```